How to make ray task async
I want to run a function (Ray Task) that may trigger another request afterward.
For example, if I have 10 tasks but only 1 CPU, the system will process one task at a time since each task requires 1 CPU.
However, each of these tasks makes an external API call.
@ray.remote
def fetch():
    request.get(...)

I would like to make this API request asynchronous and await its completion, so instead of processing one task at a time, I can run all tasks concurrently. If I call fetch 10 times, all 10 API requests should run in parallel, and once the requests are complete, each task should resume sequential processing.
How can I achieve this with Ray?

This is probably what you're after https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/ray-core/actors/async_api.html
Modified from the example
import ray
import asyncio

@ray.remote
class AsyncActor:
    # multiple invocation of this method can be running in
    # the event loop at the same time
    async def fetch(self):
        # async web request

actor = AsyncActor.remote()

async def async_get():
    await actor.fetch.remote()

asyncio.run(async_get())  # to call from synchronous context

Note that requests is not async, so you'll need to either wrap it to be asynchronous or use another web fetch library like aiohttp https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_quickstart.html

This is only for an actor. I want this to happen with my normal tasks and not actors. :(
An actor can run async only for it's own functions in it's own single core. I want all my normal @ray.remote functions (tasks) to not waste resources on ray workers. by passing the loop back to ray if it can execute other tasks in the meantime.
Is this even possible?

I'm not sure that I fully understood your answer. But maybe this snippet will give you clues how to load several urls in parallel in async:
import ray
import aiohttp
import asyncio

@ray.remote
class AsyncActor:
    async def run_task(self, url):
        print("started")
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            async with session.get(url) as response:
                data = await response.json()
        print("ended")
        return data[0] #sampling data

actor = AsyncActor.remote()
# All tasks should start at once.
urls = ["https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"] * 5
tt = ray.get([actor.run_task.remote(url) for url in urls])
print(tt)

Also you can avoid using actors by using asyncio.run inside ray worker:
import ray
import aiohttp
import asyncio


async def run_task(url):
    print("started")
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url) as response:
            data = await response.json()
    print("ended")
    return data[0] #sampling data


async def gather_urls(urls):
    tasks = [run_task(url) for url in urls]
    results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    return results

@ray.remote
def wrapper(urls):
    import asyncio
    task = gather_urls(urls)
    res = asyncio.run(task)
    return res

# # All tasks should start at once.
urls = ["https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"] * 5
tt = ray.get(wrapper.remote(urls))
print(tt)


I am trying to use async in ray workers for ray tasks. Usually a worker with 1 cpu picks the tasks up, however if the tasks call some remote api, the task blocks all other requests while it's not doing anything.

async execution as in my example fixes this. It allows to switch to other tasks while waiting for the response.

This works only for one Actor, i want it to be async on many actors on the same core. If you instantiate two actors, it swans two processes. I also don't have my functions wrapped as Actors, so those are the ones i want to be able to stop the execution flow and tell ray to just execute other tasks in the pipeline.

try to be more specific about your problem and write full code example that can show why async solution doesn't work for you.

I have added another option to my answer. Please check it.

Sadly writting code in the comment section doesn't work so well but i'll give it a shot.
@ray.remote
async def wrapper(urls):
await httpx.get()
I wan to run functions that do not block the ray process. So when multiple nodes of some other app put that task in the ray queue, all work in parallel when the fetch is happening instead of blocking like a casual requests.get function

Did you check my second example? You can't apply ray.remote to async functions directly. ray.remote must be applied to to normal function. But inside normal function you can initiate event loop. @ray.remote || def wrapper(urls): || import asyncio || ... || asyncio.run(tasks)
